# Laravel & PHP GD Library issue

Tags: php, laravel, gd

I have issue with php gd library, i just installing php gd library in my server when im hit this command it will return gd, that means gd library already installed in my server.

```
php -m | grep gd
```

But why if i acceess my website, it always return

```
GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.
```

Anyway im using laravel, i just try to change php version from 7.2, 7.3 and 7.4 and still same.

maybe someone any idea ? thanks!

Comment: restart your apache and try again

Comment: @STA recently, i just restart nginx because im using nginx, and still same.

Comment: Command line and Web php are not the same, they can have different configurations. Make sure GD is enabled in both environments

Comment: Use `phpinfo();` to check the web environment. Search for "*php gd web cli*" to see many examples.